# How do I automate renaming & moving these files in OSX, as they're created?

Tags: macos, automator

I'm using game capture software that creates a new folder every time a clip is started.  The folder format is:

- Game_Name

  - Segment_001.mp4
  - Segment.info
  - Game_Name.json

So if I take ten clips, I end up with 10 folders, and I can pull the videos out, but then I have ten clips all called Segment_001.mp4.  When a second clip is created, the folder gets created as "Game_Name 2", but the clip inside is still Segment_001.mp4.

What I would like to do is have a script that I can run on a group of files (or a folder that I can drop multiple folders into) that will pull out and rename all the video clips based on the parent folder name.  Generally these are being copied to an external hard drive, so if it could be done at the same time as it's being copied, that would be ideal.

As an example, given

- Game_Name

  - Segment_001.mp4
  - Segment.info
  - Game_Name.json
- Game_Name 2

  - Segment_001.mp4
  - Segment.info
  - Game_Name.json

The ideal result would be that this script runs, and I end up with:

- Game_Name

  - Game_Name.mp4
  - Game_Name 2.mp4

Or even better, Game_Name_01, 02, etc.